# Json.Net JsonConstructor attribute alternative for System.Text.Json

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, asp.net-core-3.0, system.text.json

In Json.Net we have JsonConstructor attribute in order to instruct deserializer that should use the constructor to create the object.

Is there alternative in System.Text.Json?

Comment: Not currently implemented, see [System.Text.Json: Custom Constructor Support #40399](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40399) *For the 3.0 release, there is no planned additional support for calling a non-default constructor during deserialization. That would have to be done by a custom converter.*

Comment: Should I make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this has now been added as of .NET 5.0 Preview 8:

[Announcing .NET 5.0 Preview 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-8/)

[JsonSerializer improvements in .NET 5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41313)

Related issue:
[JsonSerializer support for immutable classes and structs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29895)

Related pull request:
[Add [JsonConstructor] and support for deserializing with parameterized ctors](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/33444)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this library I wrote as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer polymorphism: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json

Add [JsonConstructor] attribute defined in the namespace Dahomey.Json.Attributes on your class.

```
public class ObjectWithConstructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ObjectWithConstructor(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Setup json extensions by calling on JsonSerializerOptions the extension method SetupExtensions defined in the namespace Dahomey.Json.
Then deserialize your class with the regular Sytem.Text.Json API.

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.SetupExtensions();

const string json = @"{""Id"":12,""Name"":""foo"",""Age"":13}";
ObjectWithConstructor obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjectWithConstructor>(json, options);
```